# Ctrl + A shortcut works incorrecly in Bash

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I have just finished customizing my Bash command prompt in OS X. In short, it now allows me to start typing commands from the new line:

```
alexey::machine { ~/rails/jutge } (git: static-pages) 12:55 PM
-> bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

When I decide to move to the start of the line using Ctrl + A shortcut, I go to the 4rd character, and all the three that were before it are erased (I marked the cursor position with an '$' sign):

```
-> bun$dle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

I mean, the first three characters are still displayed, but not accessible and not editable.

I would appreciate any instructions concerning how to fix it. Thank you.

My .bash_profile and .bashrc content:

```
function parse_git_branch () {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

PS1="\e[1;33m\u::\h\e[m \e[0;32m{ \w }\e[m\e[0;36m\$(parse_git_branch)\e[m\e[1;34m\@\e[m\e[1;35m\n->\e[m "
```

Comment: This can only be answered satisfactory if you post the contents of your `.bashrc` (or equivalent).

Comment: @rody_o Added it to the quiestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose the non-printing characters of PS1 in \[ ... \] so that bash can correctly compute the size of the prompt.

```
PS1="\[\e[1;33m\]\u::\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;32m\]{ \w }\[\e[m\e[0;36m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[m\e[1;34m\]\@\[\e[m\e[1;35m\]\n->\[\e[m\] "
```