# bash ctrl-A is not bringing the cursor to the beginning of line

Tags: bash, ps1

I've recently switched my default shell from csh to bash. One thing I noticed after switching that ctrl-A is not bringing the cursor to the begining of line - it brings it to somewhere in the middle if the command being typed quite long.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411941/ctrl-a-shortcut-works-incorrecly-in-bash), it seems to be related to my PS1 variable. My PS1 variable is as follows:

`export PS1="\e[47;30m[\s \t \u@\H \W] \$\e[0m"`

If I put "\[" in the beginning and "\]" in the end (i.e. `"\[\e[47;30m[\s \t \u@\H \W] \$\e[0m\]"`), the ctrl-A starts working but prompt disappears when I start typing something.

I've emacs bindings enabled (`set -o emacs`).

Please let me know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: `\[` needs to be immediately before each sequence of nonprintable characters, `\]` needs to be immediately after each sequence of nonprintable characters; otherwise, the shell's accounting of which characters do and don't move the cursor is wrong. When you put `\[` at the very beginning and `\]` at the very end, you're telling bash _nothing_ moves the cursor, and that's obviously wrong.

Comment: That said, Stack Overflow's scope is limited to questions about _writing software_; interactive environment configuration is outside it. You may find [BashFAQ #53](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053) useful, though.

Comment: Thank you, @CharlesDuffy for the Bash FAQ pointer. I was searching something like this for answer that explains it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to properly enclose the escape sequences within the `"\["` and `"\]"` characters

```
PS1="\[\e[47;30m\][\s \t \u@\H \W] \$\[\e[0m\]"
```